# что выводит cin.get()?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << cin.get();
}
```

Например, при вводе **lang** будет выведено **108**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin.get()` не выводит, а считывает очередной символ из потока ввода.

А `cout` его выводит, но выводит не как символ, а как целое число (потому что `cin.get()` возвращает `int`) - код считанного символа.

В вашем случае - `l`. См., например, [тут](https://istarik.ru/blog/programmirovanie/53.html).